# How to find this pattern with grep in a shell script?

Tags: regex, grep, sh

How can i find this pattern in grep?

```
1.1.1.1 (everything) testString (everything)
```

I means i need a search that can find out if testString is there in each of this case:

```
1.1.1.1 test1 testString test2
1.1.1.1 test1 test2 testString
1.1.1.1 testString test1 test2
```

Then, how can i get the result of the grep in form of "false" (not found) or "true" (found it) in order to pass the result to an if clause inside a shell sh script?

Comment: `grep -q '^1\.1\.1\.1 .*testString' file` , then read the `$?` . if `1`, not found. `0`, found.

Comment: It would match everyone of the three cases? If ".*" stands for everything, it wouldn't be more complete something like grep '^1\.1\.1\.1 .*testString'.* file ?

Comment: @ElisabettaFalivene I don't get you... sorry.

Comment: the `.*` regex stands for *anything* (which you, incorrectly, call *everything*).

Comment: I'm not so good at using grep, sorry, i can't explain myself. I mean, your pattern to me seems to be able to find out "at beginning of line find 1.1.1.1 (everything) testString EndOfLine" but i wanted to get the result even in the case "at beginning of line find 1.1.1.1 (everything) testString (Everything) EndOfLine".

Comment: there's no "EndOfLine" there. you have to explicitly ask for it, just like he asks for the beginng of line.

Comment: What's the difference between everything and anything, in this case? I guess in my language they sound the same ^^'

Comment: anything is just *one* thing (without specifying what it is).

Comment: @ElisabettaFalivene you can actually do a test, say string is `I am Kent`, for grep, `Kent`, `Kent$`, `.*Kent` or `.*Kent.*` all match. also match with re: `.*am` or `am.*` or `.*am.*` I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Yes, @Karoly, you're right about the endOfline. I guessed where i was confusing. I didn't mean anything as "one thing" but everything as "every number of character" for i don't really know what can be between 1.1.1.1 and the testString i'm searching for. Kent You're right. I was only a bit messing up. If you publish the answer as a plain answer i will accept it. Thank you very much to you all.

Comment: i'm telling you, use *anything*. if still confused, look up the dictionary (preferably an english-english dictionary).

Comment: Got it, using the english-english dictionary. You meant "everything" was just one thing (without specifying what is it)?

Comment: Programmatically, i meant to search "an undefined number of characthers of any possible type" and not "only one characther of any possible type"

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/ - http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/21464/use-of-everything-and-anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear. Are you looking for `testString` or `1.1.1.1` followed by `testString`?

Assuming the second case, and assuming you're reading in from a file:

```
while read line; do
  echo $line | grep -q '1\.1\.1\.1.*testString' && echo found || echo not found
done < filename.txt
```

Comment: wouldn't this print n found /not found if file has n lines?

Comment: put the pattern in quotes, otherwise there's a possibility of pathname expansion (`*`). and prefer quotes everywhere, even for `$line`, though in this case it's probably harmless.

Comment: @Kent - don't understand... I think the answer to your question is yes, is that not what is asked for?